# Extract Characters/String before Space from a factor data type column

Tags: r

I have a R data frame in which one column has factor data type with all text in that column. I want to extract string from that column considering text before space. I tried `gsub( " .*$", "", data[, 3] )`,where summary is my that field.But it is not working.
For example: My data is like `"abcd efgh ijk" & I want "abcd"`
 I tried to convert my factor field as a character field using

```
data[, 3] <- sapply(data[, 3], as.character)
```

But it's failed to retrieve the string before first space. Can you please help?

Sorry I can't able to put data here as it is a client data

Answer (score 0):

Try `gsub( "\\s.*", "", data[3,] )`  `\s` is the regular expression for white space. You need the extra \ so R doesn't interpret \ as an escape character.

```
x<-"abcd efgh ijk"
gsub( "\\s.*", "", x )
[1] "abcd"
```

Here is a useful cheat sheet of regular expressions:
https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/#downloads

Comment: Thans a lot. gsub works

Answer (score 0):

or

```
 x <- "abcd efgh ijk"
 strsplit(x, " ")[[1]][1]
```